# Send notification to user on facebook for app request?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, request

I have encountered a lot of questions for the same but no where have been given any concrete answer

I am sending invites to Facebook friends say a , b ,c and what should happen is a notification should be displayed for the app request

I have seen this in case of PININTEREST which does the same however I am trying to achieve this in asp.net. I found this [demo](http://demo.vatlab.net/InviteFriends.aspx) which is very close to what I want to achieve

The code I have so far is :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>Request Example</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <p>
      <input type="button"
        onclick="sendRequestToRecipients(); return false;"
        value="Send Request to Users Directly"
      />
      <input type="text" value="User ID" name="user_ids" />
      </p>
    <p>
    <input type="button"
      onclick="sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(); return false;"
      value="Send Request to Many Users with MFS"
    />
    </p>

    <script>
      FB.init({
        appId  : 'XXXXX',
      });

      function sendRequestToRecipients() {
        var user_ids = document.getElementsByName("user_ids")[0].value;
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'XXXXXXX',
          to: user_ids, 
        }, requestCallback);
      }

      function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'My Great Request'
        }, requestCallback);
      }

      function requestCallback(response) {
        // Handle callback here
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: [image]

When i send the request the user does not get it ... No error is displayed either

Comment: What is the problem with your code?  You have not listed any errors or problems.  What are you getting in the `response` parameter in your `requestCallback` function?

Comment: I am very new to the request dialogue what do i need to specify in the the requestCallback function?

Comment: Nothing so far - I am asking how you are aware that there is a problem - you did not specify this.   Is the user not receiving the request?  Are you getting some JavaScript errors?

Comment: Yes the user does not receive the request

Comment: Can you place a `console.log` in your callback function and update your post with the contents of the `response` parameter?

Comment: A possible reason for users not receiving the invites is that the application is in sandbox mode and that user is not listed in the appropriate group in the Roles tab of the application's settings.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this has nothing to do with your issue - but I noticed that you have an extra comma on this line - `to: user_ids,` - many (*sane*) browsers will accept this syntax but M$ Internet Explorer will throw a fit if it sees that :P

Comment: Well my friend - I am willing to bet you a beer that this is your issue.

Comment: I am very new to using the facebook api that is why ! i think i got your answer .. will revert back to u thanks for the help

Comment: No problem friend! Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two things that might be causing your requests not to go through -

- Missing or incorrect canvas URL
- Application is in sandbox mode

An application that sends requests to users **must have** a `canvas URL` specified in the application's settings.  When a user acts on a request (accepts it) he/she is redirected to the application and specifically to the canvas URL.  By not specifying a canvas URL your request is `deemed invalid` by Facebook as there is no where to redirect the user to.  The canvas URL can not be `apps.facebook.com/namespace` because your application does not sit on Facebook's domain.  You have to set the URL to **your** domain.  The page that you redirect to should again redirect the user back to your application :

```
 if(!strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"apps.facebook.com")) {
    header("location: "._fb_app_path);
    exit();
 }
```

An application in **sandbox mode** when the user being invited is not listed in the appropriate "roles" group in the application settings.  Applications in sandbox mode are only accessable to users who are developers, administrators or testers of that application.

Comment: i added the canvas url it keeps giving this errro mess when i run my code check edit

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct method (at least what we use) is:

```
function invoke_app_request(){
  var receiverUserIds = FB.ui({
      method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'MESSAGE',
      data: '',
      max_recipients: AN_INT //this is optional
    },
    function(response) {
      //whatever you do here
    }
  );
}
```

I read somewhere (don't take it 100%), that displaying notifications on invites is based on Facebook algorithms and it's not displayed on all apps. It has to do something with app activity and history.

Comment: Any invite that is sent will create a red notification bubble except app generated requests.